# Can I send requests directly to AWS SQS from a web application front end using JS?

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, queue, web-hosting, amazon-sqs

I have a web application which send frequents user activity, which in turn needs be processed later. So I want all user-activity requests stored on a queue(AWS SQS).

Can SQS be configured to accept requests directly from a web application as an AJAX request? Any help/reference URL is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its possible, you can even do it right from the browser bar, for example:

```
https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/TestQueue/?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=This+is+a+test+message
```

Just substitute your ARN and your queue name and message body

Comment: Great. Much appreciated. is it possible to block submission from from unauthorized domains? I want to stop hackers from submitting junk requests.